# Can I safely delete Hive jars from Spark dependencies?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I'm using Spark standalone without Hive enabled. According to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html):

> since Hive has a large number of dependencies, these dependencies are not included in the default Spark distribution

Yet, when I look at the jars, they are all there.

```
user@mymachine:~/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2/jars$ ls -l | grep hive
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   183472 Jun  6  2020 hive-beeline-2.3.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    43387 Jun  6  2020 hive-cli-2.3.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   436980 Jun  6  2020 hive-common-2.3.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 10839104 Jun  6  2020 hive-exec-2.3.7-core.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   116311 Jun  6  2020 hive-jdbc-2.3.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   326419 Jun  6  2020 hive-llap-common-2.3.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  8194428 Jun  6  2020 hive-metastore-2.3.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   916206 Jun  6  2020 hive-serde-2.3.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    54116 Jun  6  2020 hive-shims-0.23-2.3.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     8785 Jun  6  2020 hive-shims-2.3.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   120305 Jun  6  2020 hive-shims-common-2.3.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    12984 Jun  6  2020 hive-shims-scheduler-2.3.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   234942 Jun  6  2020 hive-storage-api-2.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    38352 Jun  6  2020 hive-vector-code-gen-2.3.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   692922 Jun  6  2020 spark-hive_2.12-3.0.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  2079585 Jun  6  2020 spark-hive-thriftserver_2.12-3.0.0.jar
```

Is it safe to remove these?